# TemplateSyntaxError at /blogapp/author/1/ Could not parse the remainder: '==user.username' from 'request.user==user.username'

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-4.0

what can we use inside {% %}  ?
Template error:
In template C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\blog\blogapp\templates\blogapp\authorview.html, error at line 7
Could not parse the remainder: '==user.username' from 'request.user==user.username'

```
1 : {% include 'blogapp/home.html' %}
   2 : {% load static %}
   3 : {% block content %}
   4 : <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blogapp/authorview.css' %}">
   5 : <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
   6 : <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   7 :  {% if request.user==user.username %} 
   8 : {{user.username}}
   9 : {% endif %}
   10 : <h1>{{user.username}}</h1>
   11 : <!-- <h1>{{request.user}}</h1>-->
   12 : {% for post in a %}
   13 : <div >
   14 :     <div class="container">
   15 :       <h2 class="display-1">{{post.title}} </h2>
   16 :       <p class="display-2">{{post.summary}}</p><br>
   17 :       <p class="display-2">{{post.Newpost}}</p>
```

Comment: `{% if request.user == user.username %} `

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i am using same

Comment: Hello @shafquetNaghmi try to add space after and before `==`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem anything inside it doesn't work  {% if request.user == user.username %}
 <P>hii i am shafquet Naghmi </P>
{% endif %}, it shows nothing

Comment: Are you sure you are passing a variable called `user` to the template?

Comment: @Jelle can u explain it little bit

Comment: @shafquetNaghmi in the line in your `views.py` where are you `render` the template, you are probably passing `request`, the template name and a dictionary with context variables. Are you passing a variable called `user` there? Check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) for more info.

Comment: @Jelle yeah i am passing it